# Schedule tasks Linux vs Windows

Tags: windows, linux, scheduled-tasks, cron, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to convert the time parameter of crontab(Linux) which is formatted like this(* * * * *) to the corresponding time parameter of schtasks(Windows) which is kind of complex then that of crontab.

I'm in the middle of writing an application for doing this and its kinda getting more and more complex since crontab have so many possibilities/permutations for providing the time parameter.

I was wondering if this is the right approach to write a program for converting the parameter, or there exist any better approach for achieving this?

And since parameters in crontab can be provided in many possible ways like (0 0 1,10,15 * *)    would schedule the task for midnight on 1st ,10th & 15th of month. So, is it possible  at all for schtasks to take parameters that can do the same kind of scheduling?

Comment: http://cronw.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these cron ports to Windows?

- [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/)
- [z-cron](http://www.z-cron.com/index.html)

Comment: I did checked them. They do provide a replacement to the schtask utility but the thing that it requires perl to be installed on the server would not work in my case.